# Script#: Support for custom exception classes

Tags: exception, script#

In Script#, is it possible to define your own exception classes? I cannot derive from Exception since it's sealed:

```
public class MyException : Exception {} // Cannot inherit from sealed class Exception
```

And if I try to throw an exception that doesn't inherit from Exception I get another error:

```
Error   22  The type caught or thrown must be derived from System.Exception
```

Seems like there is no support for this?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible.

You can't catch specific types in generated script. If you've got additional data you'd like to put on the exception, then the Exception type has members to hold on to additional data.